# boundingRectForGlyphRange always returns rect for font size 12

Tags: ios, swift, textkit

I am trying to calculate the rects of individual glyphs using `boundingRectForGlyphRange` method. Everything works well except it always returns the rect as if the font size was 12. Event though I set it to 20 in attributed string.

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: countElements(text))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: range)


let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
textContainer.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: attributedString.mutableString)

layoutManager.textStorage = textStorage
layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

let rect = layoutManager.boundingRectForGlyphRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1), inTextContainer: textContainer)
```

How do I make it return rect for text size 20 instead of 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialise `NSTextStorage` with `attributedString:`.

```
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedString)
```

instead of

```
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: attributedString.mutableString)
```